# How are threads terminated during a linux crash?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If you have a multithreaded program (Linux 2.26 kernel), and one thread does something that causes a segfault, will the other threads still be scheduled to run?  How are the other threads terminated?  Can someone explain the process shutdown procedure with regard to multithreaded programs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a fatal signal is delivered to a thread, either the `do_coredump()` or the `do_group_exit()` function is called.  `do_group_exit()` sets the thread group exit code and then signals all the other threads in the thread group to exit with `zap_other_threads()`, before exiting the `current` thread.  (`do_coredump()` calls `coredump_wait()` which similarly calls `zap_threads()`).

`zap_other_threads()` posts a `SIGKILL` for every other thread in the thread group and wakes it up with `signal_wake_up()`.  `signal_wake_up()` calls `kick_process()`, which will boot the thread into kernel mode so that it can recieve the signal, using an IPI<sup>1</sup> if necessary (eg. if it's executing on another CPU).

---

<sup>1. Inter-Processor Interrupt</sup>

Comment: Is this in get_signal_to_deliver?  It looks to me like do_group_exit is called after do_coredump (in the coredump case).  Can other threads continue to run while the coredump is being taken?  It's not clear to me what zap_threads does.

Comment: @abellia: `do_coredump()` never returns, so either it *or* `do_group_exit()` is called.  `zap_threads()` is very similar to `zap_other_threads()` - it also posts a `SIGKILL` and wakes up the target.  `do_coredump()` kills all the threads and waits for them to exit, then actually writes the core file.

Answer (score 5):

Will the other thread still be scheduled to run?

No. The SEGV is a process-level issue. Unless you've handled the SEGV (which is almost always a bad idea) your whole process will exit, and all threads with it.

I suspect that the other threads aren't handled very nicely. If the handler calls exit() or _exit() thread cleanup handlers won't get called. This may be a good thing if your program is severely corrupted, it's going to be hard to trust much of anything after a seg fault.

One note from the [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) man page:

> According to POSIX, the behaviour of a process is undefined after it ignores a SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV signal that was not generated by the kill(2) or the raise(3) functions.

After a segfault you really don't want to be doing anything other than getting the heck out of that program.